# filestack not working when sending my local files using storeURL function

Tags: javascript, ionic3, filestack

how do i upload a file link like on my computer or device using file stack api?

```
[uuid=15482A77BB814FE5] Invalid URL file file:///C:/Users/dennis/Downloads/00/26038020_10215387798356617_1605819028_o.jpg - invalid schema
```

it returns always like this but when i tried a http protocol it works fine.

also when i use pick() function its working properly but i dont what that function because it has a popup modal, can anybody help me with is this thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The storeURL function is for web URLs only. If you want to upload a local file, use the upload() function:

```
const client = filestack.init('Your_API_Key');
client.upload(file, uploadOptions, storeOptions, token);
```

As per the documentation on Filestack's website: "The first parameter to upload must be a valid File, Blob, or base64 encoded string."

Relevant docs: https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/upload-v3